# Wordpress 301 Redirects for thousands of posts

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, categories, posts

I have a site with more than 2000 links beeing redirected in my .htaccess file.

I would like to restructure my htaccess, so the 301 redirections work faster, and also do not loose any SEO.

Let's say I have 2 categories in my blog.
mysite.com/blog/old_planes 
mysite.com/blog/old_cars

that I want to redirect to 
mysite.com/blog/new_planes 
mysite.com/blog/new_cars

For each category I have a number of posts. How should I redirect them? I mean should I redirect each post and after that the category?
Redirect 301 /blog/old_planes/747 http://www.mysite.com/blog/new_planes/747
Redirect 301 /blog/old_planes http://www.mysite.com/blog/new_planes
or first redirect the category and then the posts? I want them all to work. Most important I do not want any "NOT FOUNDS" in webmaster tools.

Does the order matter?
If I want latter to add a new redirect should I search the specific category and paste it there? Or should I paste it at the end of my 2000 redirects.

Comment: I would suggest using a dedicate WP plugin to redirect bulk of posts to new address.

Comment: @anubhava And what would be the difference? The plugin will still have over 2000 redirects. And maybe it wont be that efficient. I need to do this because in WebmasterTools in SearchAppearence->html improvements I have some Duplicate meta descriptions, from the old link and new link. But when I access the old link it redirects me to the new one.

Comment: Either way you need to store 200 old and new links somewhere. Is not plugin then you can use `RewriteMap` and store all old/new links in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

For redirections, yes you can manually update your htaccess file, but I have been using a plugin that seems to fit the bill on a few sites - it makes tracking changes a lot easier in a convenient admin panel:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

Simply doing:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/old_cars /blog/new_cars
Redirect 301 /blog/old_planes /blog/new_planes
```

Is all that you need. Anything after the `old_cars/` and `old_plans/` will automatically show up in the new destination. However, since this is wordpress, you've probably got some mod_rewrite rules in your htaccess file, and these redirects will interfere with how that works. So instead, you should use mod_rewrite and add these rules **before** your wordpress rules:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/old_cars(.*)$ /blog/new_cars$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^blog/old_planes(.*)$ /blog/new_planes$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: And what if the posts name are different? Let's say I have Redirect 301 /blog/old_cars /blog/new_cars and a post /blog/old_cars/BMW-Saloon that I want to redirect to /blog/new_cars/Saloon-Cars

Comment: @ConstantinRauliuc Then you need to explicitly add a rule for that, but *before* the more general rule the redirects the entire category

Comment: Ok. So I have to redirect my posts first then the category. And do I need now the RewriteRule? or leave those redirects as they are, but only bring them near each other (group them)?

Comment: @ConstantinRauliuc you need to use `RewriteRule` if there are already `RewriteRule`'s in your htaccess file, otherwise, `Redirect` is fine.

Comment: Ok I understand. One more thing. In my old site I had a blog (With wordpress and all posts, categories) now my entire site is on wordpress and I do not have anymore a blog. So now every link that comes with domain/blog/category/post I redirect it to domain/category/subcategory/subsubcategory/post. And I ended up creating a .htaccess in a folder called "blog" so that the main .htaccess should remain smaller. Is that a good thing? Any Ideea?